# java and httpclient java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, httpclient

I have problem.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class qq {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.102/uploadtest/upload_photo");
        System.out.println("aaaa");

    }
}
```

File manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: qq
```

OS debian 8
java version:
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

And:

```
javac -cp ./lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:./lib/httpcore-4.4.5.jar:./lib/httpmime-4.2.5.jar:./lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar qq.java
jar cfm test.jar manifest.mf qq.class
```

Its ok, no error, exit code - 0.

I try:

```
# java -jar test.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient
        at qq.main(qq.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Class-path` to your manifest file? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: have you find any solution ? I am searching for this .

Comment: Didn’t think anyone is still manually setting classpath in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use **Maven** or **Gradle** because the depandances are loaded automatically.

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.1'
```